# How to stretch the card according to the content displayed in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to material UI framework, i want to stretch the grid accordingly displayed in the content. I couldn't able to do that. Can anyone help me in this?

```
<Card>
        <CardHeader
          avatar={<Avatar aria-label="recipe">S</Avatar>}
          title={
            <>
              <InputBase placeholder="Search Google Maps" margin="normal" />
              <IconButton type="submit" aria-label="search">
                <SearchIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </>
          }
        />
        <Divider />
        <CardContent
          style={{ overflow: "scroll" }}
          className={classes.contentHeight}
          id="chatList"
        >
          <div>
            <Message isSender content="Hello" />
            {this.state.data.map(item => {
              if (item.isSender) {
                return (
                  <Message isSender name="Sanjana" content={item.content} />
                );
              }
              return <Message name="Sanjana" content={item.content} />;
            })}
          </div>
        </CardContent>
        <Divider />
        <CardActions>
          <Paper className={classes.contentPaper}>
            <Input
              margin="dense"
              className={classes.input}
              placeholder="Enter a Message"
              disableUnderline
            />
          </Paper>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
```

Can anyone help me in this query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean like this?? https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-lehmann-lese0

Comment: @ManirajMurugan - Yes, If i have name in the grid, top of the message, the design is getting collapsed : (

Comment: Can you check the modified sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-shtern-rj8rq  I have modified this to have min width as 100 and provides actual width to fit content.. If you still have an issue then may I know what your actual issue after this?? Could you reproduce it in the sandbox given??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan - I have given name in this link "https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-bohr-3fy6b" , Name is showing in the middle. Could you assist me in this please?

Comment: Where do you want  the name to actually display inside that card?? Do you want it to be in left side as like hello?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan - Name should exactly up to the message content.

Comment: Really couldn't get you.. Can you make any image regarding it? Your expected result is not clear for me.. If you provide detail of your expected result, it would be easy to identify your problem and provide solution..

Comment: If you want to start with the ```hello``` text then you can look at this link https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-paper-bh6lq

Comment: If it resolves your entire issue then shall I post it as answer??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan - Sure Please go a head.

Comment: I have made it as solution please feel free to accept the solution if it resolves your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the content to stretch full width, you can use `width: "fit-content"` and assign your `width` value of 100 to `minWidth: 100`.

So your card will look like,

```
        <Card
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#eee",
            float: isSender ? "right" : "left",
            padding: 16,
            diaplay: "block",
            minHeight: 40,
            width: "fit-content",
            minWidth: 100,
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            textAlign: "center"
          }}
        >
```

To make the content left align inside card, you can assign style to `Grid` like,

```
 <Grid style={{ paddingBottom: 8, textAlign: "left" }} item xs={12}>
        <span>{name}</span>
 </Grid>
```

> [**Forked sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-paper-bh6lq)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width: 100`

```
<Card
  style={{
    backgroundColor: "#eee",
    float: isSender ? "right" : "left",
    padding: 16,
    minHeight: 40,
    width: 100,
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    textAlign: "center"
  }}
>
  {content}
</Card>
```

should be

```
<Card
  style={{
    backgroundColor: "#eee",
    float: isSender ? "right" : "left",
    padding: 16,
    minHeight: 40,
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    textAlign: "center"
  }}
>
  {content}
</Card>
```

because the `width: 100` gives it a width of 100px.

Comment: Thanks!... But i have some design issues while giving name to the content.

Comment: What kind of design issues? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I've updated the sandbox, 1. Name should be shown exactly up to the content. 2. Content are displaying extremely left and right but we need bit center but not extreme center

Comment: @Sanjana Your original question has already been answered and actually the issues you have are just CSS issues. Only you can fix them because in the end only you know how your app should look like. If you're unable to fix them then I would suggest asking a new question that describes the issues in a better way.